# Many to many relationship with SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql, entity-relationship, ssms

I have the following datatypes - House, Owner, with the primary keys houseID and ownerID respectively.

An Owner can have many Houses. And a House can Have many Owners. So I created an intermediate table HouseOwner that contains two columns, houseID and ownerID.

1. Should I make the houseID and ownerID columns a joint primary key for the HouseOwner table?
2. What about creating relationships between the HouseOnwer table and the House and Owner tables, I go to Database Diagrams and add all three tables - Now should I drag houseID from the House table onto houseID from the HouseOwner table? Or should do it the other round and drag houseID from the HouseOwner table to houseID on the House table? I am unsure of which way to do it as the dialog that pops up is looking for a Primary key table and a Foreign key table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes - Specifically, I'd do this because if you use some ORM tools (specifically EF), the many-to-many relationship would be automatically figured out when your tables are designed like this.

2) I'd suggest just doing it the old fashioned way, so you don't have to worry about the UI:

```
alter table HouseOwner
add constraint FK_HouseOwner_House
foreign key (HouseId)
references House (HouseId)
go
alter table HouseOwner
add constraint FK_HouseOwner_Owner
foreign key (OwnerId)
references Owner (OwnerId)
go
```

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: I would add an additional surrogate primary key (just an identity column) but there are a lot of discussions about this.

Question 2: the foreign keys are in your HouseOwner table and they relates to the PK of house and the other foreign key to the owner table.